# How to print out a generic list with javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

alright lets say i got a javascript that sends a time to another .asp page and recieves a list of records from the database depending on the time sent.

This is the javascript :

```
  $("button").click(function () {
            $.get("Empty2.cshtml",{
            time:"6:30",
           },function (data, status) {
                // wanna print out the data received here
            });
        });
```

and this the "Empty2" pages that takes the time and sends back the list of records:

```
@{

    hutsDBEntities db = new hutsDBEntities();
    var Time = Request["time"];

    var tt = db.Trips.Where(u=>u.Time == Time).ToList();;

    Response.Write(tt);
}
```

The trips is a table with many columns in the database (including a "time" column ofc)

**My Question is**: how can i print out the content of the object (data) in javascript anywhere on the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return the list as JSON:

```
@{

    hutsDBEntities db = new hutsDBEntities();
    var Time = Request["time"];

    var tt = db.Trips.Where(u=>u.Time == Time).ToList();;

    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Response.Write(Json.Encode(tt));
}
```

and then inside the success callback of your AJAX request you will be able to access the result:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $.get("Empty2.cshtml", { time:"6:30" }, function (data, status) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

and if you wanted to show the results in a tabular form instead of just alerting the raw JSON, you could use something like this:

```
$.get("Empty2.cshtml", { time:"6:30" }, function (data, status) {
    var result = '<table>';
    $.each(data, function() {
        // In this example TripName and TripLocation must be properties of the
        // returned JSON array
        result += '<tr><td>' + this.TripName + '</td><td>' + this.TripLocation + '</td></tr>';
    });

    result += '</table>';
    $('body').append(result);
});
```